# REST API HttpPost it's failing me

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, iis, http-post

I'm developing a REST API and I have an issue when I try to access through HTTP-POST.

In my project, in "ApiAreaRegistration" i have this definition:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "AccesoRegistro",
            "Api/Registros/Registro/{email}/{fecha}", 
            new
            {
                controller = "Registros", 
                action = "Registro", 
                email = UrlParameter.Optional,
                fecha = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

"email" and "fecha" are optional parameters.

In mi "RegistroController" I defined:

```
 public JsonResult Registro(int? id, Registro reg)
{
    switch (Request.HttpMethod)
    {
        case "POST": 
            return Json(registroManager.InsertarRegistroComidas(reg));
        case "GET": 
            return Json(registroManager.ObtenerRegistros(reg.email, reg.fecha),
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(new { Error = true, Message = "Operación HTTP desconocida" });
}
```

I want only do POST and GET methods. I'm testing with firefox plugin called "RESTED" an when I use an HTTP-GET, it is work fine. I access 
to the REST with a Get Method using: http://localhost:puerto/Api/Registros/registro/email/12-12-2000. The REST return me an expected value.

If i try to do a HTTP-POST doing http://localhost:puerto/Api/Registros/registro (without the optional parameters), the server return to me an 404 error: "Resource not found".
I set a breakpoint inside the Controller method, in switch() sentence, and when I try to access using an HTTP-POST, never execute this method.

```
public JsonResult Registro(int? id, Registro reg)
{
    switch (Request.HttpMethod) <-- Here i set the breakpoint
    {
        case "POST": 
            return Json(registroManager.InsertarRegistroComidas(reg));
        case "GET": 
            return Json(registroManager.ObtenerRegistros(reg.email, reg.fecha),
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(new { Error = true, Message = "Operación HTTP desconocida" });
}
```

I try to do this defining setting an [HttpPost] over the method like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult InsertarRegistro(Registro reg)
    {
              return Json(registroManager.InsertarRegistroComidas(reg));
    }
```

And I defined this way in the ApiAreaRegistration:

```
context.MapRoute(
        "AccesoInsertarRegistro",
        "Api/InsertarUnRegistro",
        new
        {
            controller = "Registros",
            action = "InsertarRegistro",
        }
    );
```

In RESTED, if i do an HTTP-POST using  http://server:port/api/insertarunregistro with all parameters that I need, the method "InsertarRegistro" is executed but the parameter of "Registro reg" is null, I have 5 attributes in this class and all is null.

One way returns me a 404, the other way returns me a null parameters... What can I do? What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> If i try to do a HTTP-POST doing http://localhost:puerto/Api/Registros/registro (without the optional parameters), the server return to me an 404 error: "Resource not found". I set a breakpoint inside the Controller method, in switch() sentence, and when I try to access using an HTTP-POST, never execute this method.

I guess you have two url rewrite rule in your application, one is AccesoRegistro rule another is Default rule.

The default rule is like below:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
```

So the http://localhost:puerto/Api/Registros/registro will firstly match the default rule "{controller}/{action}/{id}" not AccesoRegistro rule, it will return the 404 error.

I suggest you could put the AccesoRegistro rule before the Default rule, then it will work well.

Like below:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );

    routes.MapRoute(
"AccesoRegistro",
"Api/Registros/Registro/{email}/{fecha}",
new
{
    controller = "Registros",
    action = "Registro",
    email = UrlParameter.Optional,
    fecha = UrlParameter.Optional
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: My problem was solved ... I had a very stupid error... some lines, I had commented a code and ... I have not commented a simple label of the line [HttpGet] ... this is why my method only answered the Http-Get calls ... a stupid mistake . ..... I'm sorry and thanks for everything!